# Choose between float and decimal in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am building an E-commerce application, where in I will be storing the amount paid by customer i.e upto 2 digit decimal numbers. This amount will be used for lots of calculations like financial calculations, reporting etc.

Should I choose `decimal` or `float` for such kind of calculations?

Comment: Money in fact an integer value (when in cents), not float: one can pay, say, 125.67$ (12567 cents) or 125.68$ (12568 cents), but not 125.6799998$ (12567.99998 cents). That's why float is not a right type, use decimal instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use Decimal not float. Float numbers can be rounded incorrectly and are only approximate values. Decimal / Numeric are exact values

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html

Answer (score 2):

Never use floating point numbers when dealing with money/currencies.

Use fixed decimal point instead - store as decimal and do /100 and *100.

There are numeroues topics related to this problematics.

http://vladzloteanu.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/why-you-shouldnt-use-float-for-currency-floating-point-issues-explained-for-ruby-and-ror/

Answer (score 1):

[**Reference**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html)

> **For storing amount, i recommended to use [DECIMAL Datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) only.**

**Float numbers can be rounded incorrectly and are only approximate values.**

The **DECIMAL** and **NUMERIC** types store exact numeric data values. These types are used when it is important to preserve exact precision, for example with monetary data. In MySQL, NUMERIC is implemented as DECIMAL, so the following remarks about DECIMAL apply equally to NUMERIC.

MySQL 5.1 stores DECIMAL values in binary format. **[Precision Math](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math.html)**.

In a DECIMAL column declaration, the precision and scale can be (and usually is) specified;

**for example:**

**`salary DECIMAL(5,2)`**

> In this example, **5 is the precision and 2 is the scale**.
> The precision represents the number of significant digits that are stored for values, and the scale represents the number of digits that can be stored following the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

**`Use Decimal not float.`**

A "`float`" in most environments is a binary floating-point type. It can accurately store base-2 values (to a certain point), but cannot accurately store many base-10 (decimal) values. Floats are most appropriate for scientific calculations.

`Decimal` is an good type for most business math (but any built-in "money" type is more appropriate for financial calculations).